# jQuery - Find closest sibling to list item - next or previous

Tags: jquery, closest

I have a function that removes an li with an active class on a button click. When the active li is removed I need to transfer the active class to the closest li. Both .next and .prev work great but do not take into account if I am removing the first or last li. In this case either .next or .prev will not work.

Is there another function I can use here besides using an if statement? Unfortunately, closest did not work for me.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li class="active">List item #1</li>
<li>List item #2</li>
<li>List item #3</li>
<li>List item #4</li>
<li>List item #5</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('.conversations-wrap').on('click', '.delete-message', function(){

  // delete sidebar element
  $('.message-details.active').remove();

  // change sidebar active
  $('.message-details.active').closest('li').addClass('active');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete-message', function(){
  //add a fake class to the li you need to remove
  $('ul > li.active').addClass('toDelete');
  //check if the active li is the last one in the list or not
  //if it is a last one add the class active to previous li
  if($('ul > li.toDelete').index() == $('ul > li').length - 1){
    $('ul > li.toDelete').prev('li').addClass('active');
  }else{ // if not the last add the class active to the next li
    $('ul > li.toDelete').next('li').addClass('active');
  }
  // remove sidebar element
  $('ul > li.toDelete').remove();
});
```

```css
.active{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>List item #1</li>
<li>List item #2</li>
<li>List item #3</li>
<li>List item #4</li>
<li class="active">List item #5</li>
</ul>

<button class="delete-message">Delete Active li</button>
```

> **Note:** be sure to make all actions before you remove the item

Comment: Thanks mate that works great. I was hoping for a way to do it without an if statement but if that's the only way I'll go for it.

Comment: @ClintonGreen I think there is no way to not using if statement to check the last element or even the first one .. I'll try to think about it .. but I'm a little bit sure of there is no way

Comment: Yeah I tried to do it earlier with an If statement using li:first-of-type but couldn't figure out why it was removing the selected and the next one. It was because I was writing the active class to the other one before removing the other. Your .toDelete class saved the day. Thanks

Comment: @ClintonGreen glad it helped .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to add the active class to the closest `li`, your jQuery selector won't find any matches.  This is because you removed the matching element on the previous line of code.  Try persisting the current active element to a variable, changing the active sidebar element, and then deleting the element.

```
$('.conversations-wrap').on('click', '.delete-message', function(){

  // Get the current active element.
  var currentActive = $('.message-details.active');

  // Change the active sidebar element.
  currentActive.closest('li').addClass('active');

  // Delete the current sidebar element.
  currentActive.remove();

});
```

Comment: Sorry mate that doesn't work, it seems to do exactly what mine does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up going with. Thanks to @Mohamed-Yousef for pointing me in the right direction.

```
$('.conversations-wrap').on('click', '.delete-message', function(){

  // replace active class, otherwise we have two active classes later on
  $('.message-details.active').removeClass('active').addClass('toRemove');

  // change active class to closest li
  if ( $('.message-inbox ul li:first-of-type').hasClass('toRemove') ) {
    $('.message-details.toRemove').next('li').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.message-details.toRemove').prev('li').addClass('active');
  }

 // delete sidebar element
  $('.message-details.toRemove').fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove();

});
```